# redraw a geometry within a loop as the geometry is constructed

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I have a loop that prompts the user for input and then adds a new segment to a linestring based on that input.

```
while (data) {
  point = processData(data) // returns an array [x,y]
  linestringFeature.getGeometry().appendCoordinate(point)
  data = prompt('Enter data')
}
```

However the linestring is not drawn until the user exits the loop. I need to provide the user with visual feedback as each segment is add to the linestring. I'm using OpenLayers 6.5. Any advise on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, preferably a working [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a proper answer, but a bit long for a comment.

Just an idea, but try adding a timeout:

```
while (data) {
  point = processData(data) // returns an array [x,y]
  linestringFeature.getGeometry().appendCoordinate(point)
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    data = prompt('Enter data')
  }, 100)
}
```

100 can be any number, really.

If that works, it suggests the browser is not redrawing the page within the while loop / blocking prompt sequence.

If it does not work, let me know!

Comment: That's where I ended up. I tried various other event handlers that indicated completion (e.g. drawend, rendercomplete) none of which gave the desired result. OpenLayers just won't redraw the layer until everything completes. I get that from a performance perspective, you don't want to redraw if there are still potential changes. I just wish there was a more elegant solution in this case.

Comment: Glad that worked. I know what you mean - it would be nice if there if a better method. At least this gives you an angle of attack I suppose... A promise-based structure might do it? Create a promise. Resolve the promise based on an OL event like rendercomplete. And open the prompt on promise resolution.